# Checking number of strings inside array that can be successfully converted into a number

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, comparison, nan

Here's a description of the task I'm working on:

Write a function called countNumbers, which accepts an array of strings. The function should return a count of the number of strings in the array that can be successfully converted into a number. For example, the string "1" can be successfully converted to the number 1, but the string "hello" cannot be converted into a number.

```
countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4']); // 2
countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']); // 3
countNumbers([]); // 0
countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN']); // 3
countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']); // 4
```

My code:

```
function countNumbers(arr) {
    var count = 0;
    for (num in arr) {
        if (Number(arr[num]) !== NaN) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

When I console log (Number(arr[num]), I do see NaN in the console, however when I'm comparing in the loop, the count variable does not increase and I end up with a return value equal to the length of the array.

Any tips on what I could be doing wrong or what I overlooked are much appreciated.

Comment: `for (num in arr)` loops over the elements, not the indexes. You want `for (const num of arr)` and `if (!isNaN(num))`. Or `arr.length - arr.filter(isNaN).length`. VTC-ing as no longer reproducible or resolved in a way unlikely to help future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter with [`isFinite`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isFinite) and take the length.

> ```
> +'' -> 0
> +' ' -> 0
> ```

```js
function countNumbers(array) {
    return array.filter(isFinite).length;
}

console.log(countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4'])); // 2
console.log(countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers([])); // 0
console.log(countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' '])); // 4, now 6
```

If you really like only digits, then you could check with a regular expression.

```js
function countNumbers(array) {
    return array.filter(RegExp.prototype.test, /^\d+$/).length;
}

console.log(countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4'])); // 2
console.log(countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers([])); // 0
console.log(countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' '])); // 4
```

Comment: The last one gives 6 so sadly this doesn't quite work. `filter` is so much nicer than `reduce`, though!

Comment: as i wrote, `''` gives zero as `' '`. both strings are convertable.

Comment: Yeah but OP's requirement seems to be that they're not, which I guess is contrary to JS. I think they should revise their spec.

Comment: The last one is nice! The first one failed the test suite though :-( Regex ftw! :-)

Comment: I'm still fairly new to regex but it's becoming less daunting the more I read up/practice on it, thanks Nina!

Comment: Regex is the bomb, but I do want to say this is a situation that is *super* not-suited to regex. We can squeeze a lot more performance out of JS builtins like `parseInt` and `isNaN` than pattern-checking the string.

Answer (score 1):

Filter your arrays and get their lengths.

```js
console.log(countNumbers(['a', 'b', '3', 'awesome', '4'])); // 2
console.log(countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers([])); // 0
console.log(countNumbers(['4', '1', '0', 'NaN'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' '])); // 4

function countNumbers(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(el) {
    return parseFloat(el) == el;
  }).length;
}
```

Comment: parseFloat - nice!

Comment: Respect for the vanillaJS, I love arrow notation for one-liners though. `parseFloat(el) == el` definitely a good solution.

Comment: Classic JS. Timeless.

Answer (score 1):

You must pass `n` through `parseInt()` before passing to `isNaN()`, otherwise the space will evaluate as a 0 and count towards the total.

```js
const isNum = (n) => !isNaN(parseInt(n));
const countNumbers = (arr) => arr.filter(isNum).length;

console.log(
  countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4']), // 2
  countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']), // 3
  countNumbers([]), // 0
  countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN']), // 3
  countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']) // 4
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things straight up:

1. Loops.
2. Variables.

When you solve a problem using loops and variables, you now have two problems.

Remove the inline `console.log` to return the actual count as a number.

There may be more exhaustive or smarter checks than that, but you can easily modify the `isNum` function, without touching any of the other code.

No loops, no variables, and a separation of concerns - the `isNum` logic is not mixed with control flow.

Update: the `parseFloat` check in Alex's answer is the smarter check you are looking for.

```js
const isNum = maybeNum => (typeof maybeNum === 'number' || typeof +maybeNum === 'number') &&  !isNaN(+maybeNum) && maybeNum != '' && maybeNum != ' '

const countNumbers = arr => console.log(arr.filter(isNum).length)
   

countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4']); // 2
countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']); // 3
countNumbers([]); // 0
countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN']); // 3
countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']); // 4
```

Here is the version with the smarter check from Alex's answer. The editor doesn't support nullish coalescing, so instead of `parseFloat(maybeNum) ?? false`, you have to do it like it's still the 90's:

```
parseFloat(maybeNum) || parseFloat(maybeNum) === 0
```

```js
const isNum = maybeNum => 
  parseFloat(maybeNum) || 
  parseFloat(maybeNum) === 0

const countNumbers = arr => arr.filter(isNum).length
   
const test = arr => console.log(countNumbers(arr))

test(['a','b','3','awesome','4']); // 2
test(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100']); // 3
test([]); // 0
test(['4','1','0','NaN']); // 3
test(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' ']); // 4
```

Comment: `Array.filter().length` 100% the way to go here, solid approach. I was able to replicate the logic with just `!isNaN(parseInt(n))`.

Comment: Concise and easy to read at first glance for a beginner like me, thanks Josh! I appreciate the thorough response.

Comment: Way to go Christian! That's the elegant and smart check. You're most welcome Jonathan.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce over it and evaluate edge cases

```js
console.log(countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4'])); // 2
console.log(countNumbers(['32', '55', 'awesome', 'test', '100'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers([])); // 0
console.log(countNumbers(['4','1','0','NaN'])); // 3
console.log(countNumbers(['7', '12', 'a', '', '6', '8', ' '])); // 4

function countNumbers(arrayStrings) {
  return arrayStrings.reduce((count, string) => isNaN(string) || string.trim() === '' ? count : count + 1, 0)
}
```

Comment: Solid. But returns and braces for one-liners? :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think with `reduce` it can be done

```js
const countNumbers = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, value) => isNaN(Number(value)) ? acc : acc + 1, 0)
}

const num = countNumbers(['a','b','3','awesome','4']);
console.log(num)
```

Comment: Doesn't pass the test suite!

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of in-built 'isNaN()' function.
Simply replace your if statement with below:

```
if (!isNaN(arr[num])){
```

Answer (score -1):

The other solutions testing `isNaN(Number(character))` are better. I forgot about `isNaN` and wrote this. It performs slower and is much longer.

```
function countNumbers(array) {
    let count = 0
    for (number of array) {
      if(typeof number === 'number') {
        count++
      } else if(typeof number === 'string') {
        let isNumber
        let numberCharacters = number.split('')
        const numberRegularExpression = new RegExp(/[0-9]/)
        for(character of numberCharacters) {
          if(numberRegularExpression.test(character) !== true) {
            isNumber = false
            break
          } else {
            isNumber = true
          }
        }
        if(isNumber === true) count++
      }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Also, loops and variables! The more of those you do, the more complexity and moving parts you have to debug. Solid effort though. Pretty cool using a RegEx.

Comment: @Josh Wulf - There is no reason not to use loops and variables in code. You are ridiculous. You should know that using certain convenience functions of Array are slower performing than using for loops. Filter is actually a loop that iterates through all elements of an array, and it performs slower than for loops across the board. I recommend keeping your comments constructive and avoid passive agressive remarks like "Solid effort though." Its actually a viable solution for many cases. I even pointed out that another solution on the thread might be better. Maybe write a blog where you critique?

Comment: I apologise that it landed like that for you @Miaplacidus. That was not my intention. I'll take your suggestion onboard and write a blog post. Yes, functional code must have underneath an imperative implementation, because that is how processors implement it, and well-written imperative code will outperform functional code in applications where execution time is critical.

Comment: OK, I did it. Here it is: https://www.joshwulf.com/blog/2020/02/just-say-no-to-loops-and-variables/